# Magento 1.9 Intenso Theme filter issue

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I am having problem with the navigation filter.

My developer has left us long back and when we bought this theme on our filter we had an option of `view all` for those title which had long search terms like for brand it shows all brands but because of this view all feature we can see 5,6 brands then by clicking it we can see more.

My problem here is the developer had removed that view all option from the filter long back and we need it back as we have a lot of brands that came in.

I tried doing it from the `filter.phtml` file but it didn't work as its not changed from there.

Can I have some help ?
For reference, here's the link : https://stage.kiabza.com/mens-preowned-fashion.html

Comment: With this information, it is complicated for us to know what your developer has done, if he commented or deleted from the code, if you have some js error, if you have a configuration in your theme etc ...

Answer (score 0):

For intenso theme there are already setting given in admin>System>Configuration>Intenso Theme>Layered Navigation section and change value in "Number of Visible Filter Options" textbox.Please check attached image.

[image] Hope it works.

Comment: yes this option help me get 5 at a time but then the "view all" option is not there .check the same link i made the changes. thanks

Comment: You have to check in skin/frontend/intenso/default/js/intenso.js file where i think show more logic added. Please check that some code commented or not.

Comment: yes i did copy pasted old theme jss with new but it still didn't solve my problem.

Comment: After view page source i found that there are<style>.show-more{display:none;}</style> line added. Have you tried with removed it?

Comment: no i didn't do anything, maybe the developer might have done, can you tell me the solution what should i do ?. Thanks

Comment: Please enable template path hint and check phtml files related to intenso layered navigation. I think this file you have to check first:-frontend/intenso/default/template/itactica_layerednavigation/catalog/layer/view.phtml